# using an item in ng-repeat for ng-model of a select element when the objects are in different scopes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object:

```
$scope.recipe = 
  {
  ...,
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "foodItem": "Cabbage",
      "condition": "Chopped",
      "amount": "3 cups"
    },
    {
      "foodItem": "Carrot",
      "condition": "Grated",
      "amount": ".5 cups"
    },
    {
      "foodItem": "Rice Wine Vinegar",
      "condition": "",
      "amount": ".25 cups"
    },
    {
      "foodItem": "Sesame Seed Oil",
      "condition": "",
      "amount": "3 tablespoons"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

I am using ng-repeat to create a select dropdown for every ingredient in the object above (or whatever recipe I select).

I have another object:

```
$scope.foods = 
[
  {
    "name": "Baking Powder",
    "_id": "pJ7ERDIbL9QTDRPn"
  },
  {
    "name": "Beef",
    "_id": "e9HWiXFflHTuwHHP"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bread",
    "_id": "2fFCSMJRYURINLrE"
  },
  {
    "name": "Butter",
    "_id": "SiSryQYOkvUDoxix"
  },
...
]
```

That I will use for the options for each of the dropdowns that are created with ng-repeat.  I want to use each of the foodItems in recipe as the default selection in each of the select dropdowns (using ng-model).  Based on other SO posts I've read this seems to work with an input element using ng-model in an ng-repeat but not with a select using ng-model with ng-option in an ng-repeat.  Is there any way to do this with a select?

html:

```
<!-- TODO Add a directive to this div element so that it repeats 
    for each recipe ingredient to display. -->
  <div class="ingredient-row" ng-repeat="item in recipe.ingredients">
    <div class="prefix-20 grid-30">
      <p>
        <!-- TODO Add directives to this select element to bind its value 
          to the recipe ingredient model's `foodItem` property and to 
          populate the list with the food items from the database. -->
        <select ng-model="item.foodItem" ng-options="food.name for food in foods">
          <option value="">Select Item</option>
        </select>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-30">
      <p>
        <!-- TODO Add a directive to this input element to bind its value 
          to the recipe ingredient model's `condition` property. -->
        <input type="text" value="{{item.condition}}">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-15">
      <p>
        <!-- TODO Add a directive to this input element to bind its value 
          to the recipe ingredient model's `amount` property. -->
        <input type="text" value="{{item.amount}}">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-5 pad-top">
      <p class="flush-right">
        <!-- TODO Add a directive to this anchor element so that you can 
          delete the recipe ingredient when the user clicks on the 'Delete' link. -->
        <a class="no-action-link"> <img src="images/delete.svg" height="12px"> </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('RecipeDetailController', function($scope,dataService,$location) {

    const init = () => {
      let id = $location.path();
      id = id.slice(6);
      let category;
      console.log(id);

      dataService.getID(id,function(response) {
        $scope.recipe = response.data;
        $scope.title = response.data.name || 'Add New Recipe.';
        category = response.data.category;
      });

      dataService.getAllCategories(function (response) {
        $scope.categories = response.data;
        let index = response.data.findIndex(item => item.name === category);
        if (index === -1) {
          $scope.initial = {"name": "Choose a Category"};
        } else {
          $scope.initial = $scope.categories[index];
        }
      });

      dataService.getAllFoodItems(function (response) {
        $scope.foods = response.data;
      });
    }

    $scope.addIngredient = () => {
//      console.log($scope.recipe);
      let ingredient = '';
      $scope.recipe.ingredients.push('');
    };

    $scope.ingredientDetails = function(ingredient) {
      if (ingredient === null) {
        $scope.condition = '';
        $scope.amount = '';
      } else {
        $scope.condition = ingredient.condition;
        $scope.amount = ingredient.amount;
      }
    };

    $scope.cancelChanges = () => {
      $location.path('/');
    }

    init();

  });
```

Comment: it's not really possible to answer the question without seeing the data you are binding here;  The way the default option works with `ng-options` is that if the value in the `ng-model` property is exactly equal to a value in the repeated elements, that will be chosen as default automatically.  Therefore, unless you have a data type mismatch, this should already be doing what you expect.

Comment: Use and create a filter

Comment: I rewrote the question to better explain what I am trying to do.  I wondering if this is even possible without the recipe object being a part of the food object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simplified plunker of your HTML, and recreated your scenario, using static data (and changing the data so that the values in `$scope.recipe.ingredients` match what is in `$scope.foods`).

In your case, the `ng-options` form that you are using is still attempting to assign the value as an object rather than as a string.  This ends up creating an output HTML like:

```
<option label="Cabbage" value="object:8">Cabbage</option>
```

By changing the `ng-options` slightly, we can get the desired output.

```
<select ng-model="item.foodItem" ng-options="food.name as food.name for food in foods">
```

results in an output of:

```
<option label="Cabbage" value="string:Cabbage" selected="selected">Cabbage</option>
```

This slight change in output is enough for angular to find the string value match from `$scope.recipe.ingredients`, and set a default value.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3l1afYx4n4xRAlPuzWkZ?p=preview